# ValueError on conversion from string array to num array, invalid literal when using command argument?

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to write a program that takes the numbers 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 101 as command arguments and calculate the log, sine, square, and cosine of these numbers and write the results to a csv file. I keep getting a ValueError, which is at the bottom. This is what I have so far:

```
import sys
import math
import csv

print("the name of the program is ", sys.argv[0]) 
  
n = len(sys.argv[1]) 
a = sys.argv[1][1:n-1] 
a = a.split('; ') 
  
for i in a: 
    print(i) 
def main():
    # reading only the numbers from command line
    # and storing it in the list num_list

    str_num = sys.argv[1::] # ['1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '101']
    
    
    num_list = [int(num) for num in str_num] # [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 101]
    
    
    with open('results.csv', mode = 'w') as output_file:
        output_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter = ';')
        
        
        for num in num_list: 
            row = []
            row.append(math.log(num))
            row.append(pow(num, 2))
            row.append(math.sin(num))
            row.append(math.cos(num))
            
            output_writer.writerow(row)
    
main()
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-738df23d937b> in <module>
     38             output_writer.writerow(row)
     39 
---> 40 main()

<ipython-input-5-738df23d937b> in main()
     19 
     20     # converting string array to int array
---> 21     num_list = [int(num) for num in str_num] # [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 101]
     22 
     23     # open 'results.csv' with write mode

<ipython-input-5-738df23d937b> in <listcomp>(.0)
     19 
     20     # converting string array to int array
---> 21     num_list = [int(num) for num in str_num] # [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 101]
     22 
     23     # open 'results.csv' with write mode

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-f'
```

Comment: What arguments are you passing to the program?

Comment: The math.sin(num), math.log(num), math.cos(num), pow(num,2). Should I have included it earlier in the code?

Comment: I mean through the command line. The error you're getting is saying you're passing the string `-f` to `int()`, so `str_num` may not be what you think it is.

Comment: I think same with @montgomery-watts. Check the type and format of your `str_num` by printing or else way. Maybe also try `num_list = int(num.strip())`